# Input data is not loading into database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am encountering the following problem: I have a program that is supposed to load some data into a database, and it is not working. No errors are popping out, it just does not load and save the data.

Here is the connection code:

```
public Conexion()
{
    string dataSource = ".\\SQLEXPRESS";
    string rutaBase = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"/App_Data/Database1.mdf");
    cadenaConexion = "Data Source=" + dataSource + ";AttachDbFilename=\""
        + rutaBase + "\";Integrated Security=true;User Instance=True";
}
```

Edit 1: Here is the code used to insert the data and a screen capture of the server explorer.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Persistencia
{
    public class PersistenciaEmpresaAuspiciante
    {
        readonly Conexion conexion = new Conexion();

        public bool ExisteAuspiciante(EmpresasAuspiciantes pAuspiciante)
        {
            if (pAuspiciante == null)
                return false;

            string sql = "Select * FROM AUSPICIANTES WHERE IdAuspiciante=" + pAuspiciante.idAuspiciante.ToString();
            DataSet resultado = conexion.Seleccion(sql);

            if (resultado == null)
                return false;

            return resultado.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0;
        }

        public bool AltaAuspiciante(EmpresasAuspiciantes pAuspiciante)
        {
            if (pAuspiciante == null)
                return false;

            if (ExisteAuspiciante(pAuspiciante))
                return false;

            string sql = "INSERT INTO AUSPICIANTES (IdAuspiciante, NombreAuspiciante) Values"
                + pAuspiciante.idAuspiciante.ToString() + ", '"
                + pAuspiciante.nombreAuspiciante + " ', '"
                 + "')";
            return conexion.Consulta(sql);
        }

        public bool BajaAuspiciante(EmpresasAuspiciantes pAuspiciante)
        {
            if (pAuspiciante == null)
                return false;

            if (!ExisteAuspiciante(pAuspiciante))
                return false;

            string sql = "DELTE FROM AUSPICIANTES WHERE IdAuspiciante=" + pAuspiciante.idAuspiciante.ToString();
            return conexion.Consulta(sql);
        }

        public bool ModificarAuspiciante(EmpresasAuspiciantes pAuspiciante)
        {
            if (pAuspiciante == null)
                return false;

            if (!ExisteAuspiciante(pAuspiciante))
                return false;

            string sql = "UPDATE AUSPICIANTES SET"
                + "NombreAuspiciante" + pAuspiciante.nombreAuspiciante
                + "' WHERE IdAuspiciante =" + pAuspiciante.idAuspiciante.ToString() + ";";
            return conexion.Consulta(sql);
        }

        public List<EmpresasAuspiciantes> ListaAuspiciante()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM AUSPICIANTES";
            DataSet resultado = conexion.Seleccion(sql);
            List<EmpresasAuspiciantes> lista = new List<EmpresasAuspiciantes>();

            if (resultado == null)
                return lista;

            DataRowCollection tabla = resultado.Tables[0].Rows;

            foreach (DataRow fila in tabla)
            {
                object[] elementos = fila.ItemArray;
                EmpresasAuspiciantes auspiciante = new EmpresasAuspiciantes();
                auspiciante.idAuspiciante = int.Parse(elementos[0].ToString());
                auspiciante.nombreAuspiciante = elementos[1].ToString();
                lista.Add(auspiciante);
            }

            return lista;
        }
    }
}
```

[Database explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8c2a.png)

Connection string for the `.mdf` file:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\srjua\OneDrive\Escritorio\ctc\Codificacion, persistencia y controladora 2\WebApplication1\App_Data\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: You may write the code which is used to post data to be able to help!

Comment: Probably you are writing to the wrong database or server.  The database is probably already attached to the server.  The only time you use the mdf filename in a connection string is you have a Local Database.  So remove the AttachDbFilename.  The DataSource should be the Server name and Instance shown on the login windows of SQL Server Management Studio.  If the server has more than one Database then you need to specify the database either in the connection string (Initial Catalog=myDataBase;) or with a "USE" in the COMMAND TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

> You are doing wrong on your `dataSource` for `LocalDb` operation. it
>   should be `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Your Connection String should look like this:

```
public Conexion()
{
    string dataSource = "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB";
    string rutaBase = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"/App_Data/Database1.mdf");
    cadenaConexion = "Data Source=" + dataSource + ";AttachDbFilename=\""
        + rutaBase + "\";Integrated Security=true;";
}
```

Normally it should be like

```
 string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBaseName.mdf;Connect Timeout=30;Integrated Security=True;";
```

> ***Note :*** `LocalDB instances` are all `User Instances`, and there's no need to specify `User Instance=true` in your connection string, in
>   fact it is not even supported ([as you can see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-express-user-instances)). Just get rid of this part
>   and it's going to work fine

You could refer [Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string#sql-server-express-localdb)

Hope this would help.

Comment: I' ve tried changing the datasource like you are saying but an error pops up. "Unrecognized scape sequence".

Comment: Please include your insert command code base on question. Other then its tough to assist you got my point?

Comment: Try with my normal way , I am pretty sure you are also doing mistake on putting `/`

Comment: put extra @ before data source like this ` @"Data Source`, another things is you haven't open your connection how would the query be executed.

Comment: Another hints you also can try with `string dataSource = ".\SQLEXPRESS";` just get rid of one (\) back slash   instead of  two (\\)  that might works

Comment: Hello I have updated answer as another problem found on your code. Please have a try and let me know.